# What are some of the main conventions used in Gramps?

Tags: gedcom, naming-convention, gramps, evidence

As I have started recording my family history using evidence based methods in Gramps I've noticed that it is very flexible (too flexible?). I worry that the method in which I record data might seem sensible at first but after running reports or exporting my data I will notice issues with my data that will require bulk editing because I wasn't using a Gramps convention. For example, I'm not sure if it is better to record the details of a marriage in an event or family object and how that will affect GEDCOM exporting.

What are some of the major conventions of entering data into Gramps and what resources are available to help me figure out how to store data in the most 'future-proof' way?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  Looking at your question it seems to be asking two questions: "How to record marriages in Gramps?" and "Whether there are resources to advise how to record in Gramps generally?".  At the same time we are very keen to see more questions here during our Beta.  Is there any chance that you may be able to edit this question to focus on the first, and ask a new question for the second?  While waiting for answers you may also like to look at and vote on [other Gramps Q&As here](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gramps).

Comment: @stevemonster As not all users are Gramps users and may not be following your question can you provide a screenshot or some other visual example (with non-living person), such as Gramps vs. GEDCOM which also may answer your own question. Perhaps restating the question as "How do I enter things into Gramps so that it is inline with GEDCOM on export?"

Answer (score 6):

I suggest that you start at our portal: https://gramps-project.org/wiki/index.php?title=Portal:Using_Gramps

There's a lot to read over there, including suggestions on how to record data in various forms.

On the subject of marriage, Gramps is not much different from other GEDCOM based software, in the sense that you can follow what I think is common. You record date and place in events, and marriage events are commonly attached to families.